# Date get erased on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form which is in a updatePanel, I am putting masks on all my date fields like so:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //phone numbers
    DoMasks();    
});

function DoMasks() {
    //dates
    var txtADate = $("#<%=txtADate.ClientID%>");
    $(txtADate).mask("99/99/9999");
    var txtDOB = $("#<%=txtDOB.ClientID%>");
    $(txtDOB).mask("99/99/9999");
}
```

When I fill out a blank form and put the `adate` in, and then select a drop down (which causes postback) the date in the `adate` textbox get erased. when I comment out `DoMasks();` everything works fine, so it must be something there? please assist.

It works fine if I open a form that already has data saved in it, and the dates are all already filled in, very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the format of the date being passed back after the postback? If the date comes back as  something like `09-30-2013` that mask will clear the value since it's looking for a date in the format of `09/30/2013`. (note the slashes)

Make sure your dates are coming back with `/`. You can do this using a format string like so:

```
myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: hm, i guess it comes back with however i type in, so in this case it'll be 09/30/2013 as it's what the js formatting is set to. It's a new form, i'm not populating it with anything, except for what the user puts in.

Comment: thank you! you were right! when i typed in the date, it ofcouse put it in the right format, but when i use the calendar extender to populate the date, it puts in it 8/30 instead of 08/30. thanks for pointing me in the right direciton!